# Many to many relationship with various options

Tags: php, mysql, many-to-many

Ok, I've been trying to find a solution for this and I sort of did, although not perfect, and I have a feeling there probably might be a better one.

This is a bit tricky, I have 3 tables -

cart -

```
id | name
----------
1  | x
.. | ..
```

cart_items -

```
cart_id | item_id
------------------
1       | 1
1       | 2
2       | 1
2       | 3
```

items -

```
id | color | shape | size | ...
-------------------------------
1  | blue  | round | big  | ...
2  | *     | rect  | small| ...
3  | red   | *     | big  | ...
```

(This table has wildcards that match any option)

Now there is a many to many relationship, so far nothing special.
What I get as input is a list of groups of characteristic (color, shape, size etc.), and I need to bring the relevant carts that have those items that match those characteristics.

For instance - a user queries for a cart that has 2 items - 
One is big and blue
Seconds is small and round

What I do there is fetch a list of item id's that match the first item requirements and another list that match the second's.
With those two lists I should query to get a cart that has 2 items that match those characteristics (at least).
Let's say I received from this query two lists of items -
For the first - (1,3,5,6,7)
For the second - (3,4,7,9,15)

What would be the best query to make sure my cart has 2 items, one from the first list and the second from the second list. I should say that number of items can be more than 2.

The solution I found is concatenating 'EXISTS' conditions, something like this -

```
SELECT DISTINCT(cart_id) FROM cart_items ci WHERE 
EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM cart_items WHERE cart_id = ci.cart_id AND item_id IN <list 1>) 
AND EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM cart_items WHERE cart_id = ci.ci_cart_id AND item_id IN <list 2>)
AND ...<keep concatenating as long as needed>
```

Sorry for the long description, any advice?

Comment: If only one person answered so far does that mean my solution is perfect? (I doubt)

Answer (score 1):

This is somewhat simplified if you model the query itself as a table (but for an optimal solution you would generate the query - but creating SQL using SQL is not for the faint of heart, and you've not tagged this with any other language). Hence...

```
CREATE TABLE queries (
   query_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
   color VARCHAR (20),
   shape VARCHAR (20),
   size VARCHAR (20),
   PRIMARY KEY (query_id, color, shape, size)
);
INSERT INTO queries (query_id, color, shape, size)
VALUES (1, 'blue', '*', 'big');
INSERT INTO queries (query_id, color, shape, size)
VALUES (2, '*', 'round', 'small');
```

Then you can identify the matching items with:

```
SELECT i.id
FROM items i
INNER JOIN queries q
ON q.color IN (i.color, '*')
AND q.size IN (i.size, '*')
AND q.shape IN (i.shape, '*')
WHERE q.query_id=1;
```

Then you just need to join this to cart_items to get the matching carts....

```
SELECT q.query_id, ci.cart_id
FROM items i
INNER JOIN queries q
ON q.color IN (i.color, '*')
AND q.size IN (i.size, '*')
AND q.shape IN (i.shape, '*')
INNER JOIN cart_items ci
ON i.id=ci.item_id
WHERE q.query_id IN (1,2);
```

Lastly you just need to identify cart_ids that match both queries:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT q.query_id), ci.cart_id
FROM items i
INNER JOIN queries q
ON q.color IN (i.color, '*')
AND q.size IN (i.size, '*')
AND q.shape IN (i.shape, '*')
INNER JOIN cart_items ci
ON i.id=ci.item_id
WHERE q.query_id IN (1,2)
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT q.query_id)=2;
```

Comment: Thanks @symcbean ! I might have not been clear on all the scenarios, but your solution doesn't include a case where a cart has 2 items of type id = 1, for instance, which is possible.
For instance, a user queries for a cart that has two items which match characteristics of items #1 and #2, your solution will also return a cart that has two items of type #1 since they are both IN (1,2).
I'm using PHP btw.